# vlookup with wildcard not working

Tags: excel

I'm working with a few large spreadsheets and I can't seem to get vlookup to work.

Here is what I'm trying to do - in the spreadsheet I'm working on I need excel to look at Column B for the item code (09-K1450V/XXXL for example). Then look at a different sheet in column AM for a similar item code and finally spit back the color.

`VLOOKUP(B4539&"*",MARKETING!AM3:AM5428,71,FALSE)`

Now the only issue (but wildcard should be taking care of this) is that on my Marketing sheet the item codes look like "09-K1450" without the size or anything else.

Comment: This would only work in reverse.  You are looking for any thing that has `09-K1450V/XXXL` at the beginning, not the other way around.  You will need to use an Array form of INDEX/MATCH with SEARCH().

Comment: Or if the pattern is the same you can always use Left() to isolate the correct matches.

Comment: ah I see - excel can't do a "is like" type of wildcard. Ok I'll create a different formula to look at the first set of characters before the slash

Comment: Still can't get this to work. Here is what I changed the formula to. thoughts?`VLOOKUP(LEFT(B4539,FIND("/",B4539&"/")-1),MARKETING!$C$3:$C$5428,71,FALSE)`

Comment: you are only looking at one column in your second criteria, yet you tell the vlookup you want column 71.  The third criteria is relative to the range set in the second criteria.  So the if there is only one column in the second criteria the third can only be 1.  You will need to make the the second criteria larger.

Comment: that's what I thought but no go on a range either

`VLOOKUP(LEFT(B4539:B4643,FIND("/",B4539:B4643&"/")-1),MARKETING!C3:C5428,71,FALSE)`

Comment: or:
`VLOOKUP(LEFT(B4539,FIND("/",B4539&"/")-1),MARKETING!A1:DI2242,71,FALSE)`


why can't excel do this? According to the docs, the formula wizards and the way I've done it in the past, this should work.

Comment: You changed the Left function.  Do not change that.  Change the Second criterion in the VLOOKUP. `MARKET‌​ING!C3:C5428` is refering to only one column.  but you are telling the VLOOKUP that it should have at least 71 with the third criteria.  Either you need to add 70 columns to the `MARKET‌​ING!C3:C5428` or change the 71 to 1.

Comment: Look at what the return of `=LEFT(B4539,FIND("/",B4539&"/")-1)` and make sure that it is found in column A of your marketing sheet.  It needs to be an exact match. no extra characters.

Comment: looks like I may be back to the wildcard function. Some of the rows in marketing have the /XXXL and some don't. So how to set the LEFT formula so it finds everything before the slash (as it is now) and then wildcard in case there is additional information on Marketing

Comment: `LEFT(B4539,FIND("/",B4539&"/")-1) & "*"`

Comment: Basically make the Left() function return the smallest unique string and add the wild card to include those that have extras.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Craner had the answer:

`=VLOOKUP(LEFT(B4539,FIND("V",B4539&"V")-1) & "*",MARKETING!C3:DX5429,69,FALSE)`

Comment: Glad you were able to find the answer.